# How make this program terminate after

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

Below is a simple program that I wrote that will ask for a password. If I enter the incorrect password I am prompted with "Password incorrect would you like to try again?", and if I say no or anything else that doesn't begin with a 'y', it will terminate the program. The problem is, if I enter the correct password which is "Noah" it says "Password correct" and it loops back to "Enter password" again. How can I make this program terminate after I enter the correct password? Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class methods
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String response = "yes";
      System.out.println("Enter password:");
      while(response.charAt(0)=='y')
      {
         String input = sc.nextLine();
         if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Noah")==true)
         {
            System.out.println("Password correct");
         }
         else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Noah")==false)
         {
            System.out.println("Password incorrect, would you like to try again?");
            response = sc.nextLine();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `input.equalsIgnoreCase("Noah")==true` Remove the `==true`, I get angry when I see this.

Comment: also the "if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Noah")==false)" is not needed, it if it's not true, its false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  while(response.charAt(0)=='y')
      {  System.out.println("Enter password")
         String input = sc.nextLine();
         if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Noah")==true)
         {
            System.out.println("Password correct");
            break;
         }
         else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Noah")==false)
         {
            System.out.println("Password incorrect, would you like to try again?");
            response = sc.nextLine();
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

use `break;` then you can terminate.

```
if("Noah".equalsIgnoreCase(input)){
    System.out.println("Password correct");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways. In increasing severity:

1) Use a `break` statement. That will take program control flow to just after the end of the `while` loop.

2) Use a `return` statement. That will exit the function and, in your specific case, that will end the program.

3) Insert `System.exit(n)` where `n` is a number, probably non-zero, to indicate a return status. This terminates the Java Virtual Machine, and returns the value `n` to the operating system.

In your case I'd be inclined to go with (1) or (2).

Answer (score 1):

`if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Noah")==true)
         {
            System.out.println("Password correct");
            break;

         }`

or you can add `response ="no";`

`if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Noah")==true)
         {
            System.out.println("Password correct");
            response ="no";

         }`

" no" or anything that dose not start with the 'y' char .

Answer (score 0):

After doing a couple of changes, I guess this is what you are looking for :

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Methods{

```
public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String response = "yes";

    while(response.charAt(0)=='y'){
         System.out.println("Enter password:");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Noah")==true){
            System.out.println("Password correct");
            break;
        }
        else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Noah")==false){
            System.out.println("Password incorrect, would you like to try again?");
            response = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

}